# Safe way to negate a number of type std::size_t

Tags: c++

When I want to negate a number of type `std::size_t`, I usually do `-static_cast<int>(number)`. However, I understand that the number might not fit into an `int`. So, my question is what is a safe portable way to do this?

Comment: You mean `float nRec = -1.0f / number;`?

Comment: @H2CO3: Sorry, I meant negation not negative reciprocal.

Comment: @JesseGood then just cast to ssize_t

Comment: I think you have an inherent problem in that you can't possibly get the negative value of at least half the range of a `std::size_t`, since a `std::ssize_t` can only describe half the values in the range of `std::size_t`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: `std::ssize_t` is part of POSIX and not standard C++, correct?

Comment: Just a minor point...  Why would you want to negate it?  Are you adding and subtracting sizes from one-another?  In my experience (although perhaps it's only due to 'normal' architectures) you can still do this, even though there is no negative value - overflow still works correctly.  That's the whole basis of fixed-point algorithms (though I wouldn't use `size_t`).

Comment: @paddy: I'm using negative offsets to parse very large files. It is very unlikely that I will have overflow, but I was curious if there is a portable safe solution that I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no safe portable way to do this.

`size_t` is an unsigned type. There is no guarantee that there is *any* signed integer type big enough to hold the maximum value of `size_t`.

If you're able to assume that the value you're negating isn't too big, you can convert it to `long long` (if your compiler supports it) or `long` (if it doesn't):

```
size_t s = some_value;
long long negative_s = -(long long)s;
```

If you're worried about overflow, you can compare the value of `s` to `LLONG_MAX` before doing the conversion.

Comment: Would `ptrdiff_t` be better than `long`?

Comment: Nitpick: you should use `std::numeric_limits<long long>` instead of `LLONG_MAX`

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question, although the example is more `C` than `C++`.

Answer (score 1):

`-static_cast<int>(number)` is *safe*; the result of the `static_cast` is implementation-defined if it would not fit in an `int`.

To detect if the result would not fit:

```
(number <= std::numeric_limits<int>::max()) ? -static_cast<int>(number) : ...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? The fact that it's implementation-defined means it's not portable, which is often what people mean by "safe".

Comment: @KevinBallard it's not undefined behaviour.  The fact that it may give different results on different platforms doesn't necessarily stop it being portable; it depends how the end result is going to be used.

Answer (score 1):

The safe way checks whether the variable fits into the corresponding signed type:

```
typedef std::size_t my_uint;
typedef typename std::make_signed<my_uint>::type my_int;

my_uint n = /* ... */;

if (n > std::numeric_limits<my_int>::max()) { /* Error! */ }

my_int m = -static_cast<my_int>(n);
```

You need to `#include <limits>` and `<type_traits>`.

(Or wrap everything into one line:)

```
if (n > std::numeric_limits<typename std::make_signed<decltype(x)>::type>::max()) { /* Error! */ }
```

Comment: Neat, but won't that turn an `unsigned long` into a `long` instead of a `long long`? The latter seems to be what's required, since the maximum `unsigned long` won't fit into a `long`.

Comment: @KevinBallard: If you don't like `make_signed`, you can write your own `make_as_large_as_possible` trait!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an inherent problem in that you can't possibly negate the value in the upper-half range of a `std::size_t` using `std::ssize_t`, since a `std::ssize_t` can only describe half the values in the range of `std::size_t`.  For instance, if you had a `unsigned char` value of 255, you could never get a `signed char` value of -255 ... you'd need a larger type, like a `signed short`.  If `std::size_t` is the largest integral container of your platform, then you simply aren't going to be able to describe those values in a "negative" format without designating some custom data-type such as a `struct` with an extra flag variable for designating the sign of the value.  That of course is no longer "portable"...

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answer, so I guess portable is out of the question.

Comment: Not if you want to keep the entire range of a `std::size_t` if in-fact the `std:size_t` is the largest integral value your machine describes ... the only "portable" solutions would involve some type of clipping of the range like the other answers have listed.